# Evans PDE Notation Chapter 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

1. Page 2 in the Introduction chapter defines a linear PDE as

$$ \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_{\alpha}(x)D^\alpha u = f(x)$$

Now, in Appendix A, Evans defines for a "multi-index" $\alpha = (\alpha_1...\alpha_n)$, where each component is a non-negative integer, $$ D^\alpha u = \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} u}{\partial^{\alpha_1}x_1...\partial^{\alpha_n}x_n}.$$ Now, the fact that it is $ |\alpha| \leq k $ in the summation makes me think that $ \alpha $ is such a multi-index. However, in that case, the notation $ a_{\alpha}(x) $ does not make sense - shouldn't it be $ a_{|\alpha|}(x) $ instead? What does he mean to sum over here?

Comment: They are assigning a different coefficient to each combination of partial derivatives, and you need a multi-index for both. They are summing over $|\alpha|\le k$ so that all indices i.e. all partial derivatives of order $\le k$ are accounted for. Using $a_{|\alpha|}$ would be insufficient as that would assign the same coefficient to $\partial^3_{xyz}$ as it would to $\partial^3_{yzx}$ which isn't super general

Comment: That makes sense! I suppose I was confused because, so far, I've only seen indexing of coefficients with integers, rather than with vectors (which is what a multi-index essentially seems to be).